# Visual maps of the neuronal membrane

Tags: proteins, neurophysiology, literature, neurotransmitter

There are lots of visual maps of the brain as a whole, especially the cortex, that show the distribution of "features" over a two-dimensional map, e.g. the [Brodman areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brodmann_area) (their morphology and their functions), or the cortical [homunculi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortical_homunculus).

What I would like to literally **see** - on a quite different level of resolution - are density distributions of some "items" over the membrane of some prototypical neurons, especially:

- excitatory synapses
- inhibitory synapses (mainly on the soma?)
- vesicles (not *in*, but *near* the membrane)
- receptors (not only at and near synapses?)
- the different [ion channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_channel)
- [electrical synapses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_synapse)
- [sodium–potassium pumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%2B/K%2B-ATPase)

So my question is for instructive graphical displays of such distributions, may it be in an article, on a website, or in a book.

(I assume that none of the items above is distributed evenly. But maybe some *are* on a specific type of neuron?)

Comment: I can easily answer about excitatory synapses and perhaps about receptors, and some ion channels but your question is too broad and I'm afraid any answer is going to be too lengthy. Please consider breaking it up.

Comment: Why not breaking up answers? I am not especially interested in one of the "items", any single example is welcome (but of course I would appreciate as many as possible - this would allow for comparisons and detecting of correlations). At other StackExchange sites such questions are called "big list" question and are rather well-liked.

Comment: With biology, though, there is bound to be nuance involved. So, a whole discussion is required for any of the 'items'. Furthermore, when you ask about categories such as 'receptors' or 'ion channels' which each have numerous members you are expanding the scope of the question (and the answer) substantially. Lastly, you are not asking for just a list but rather the full distribution of each category on a cell, which requires more than just mentioning a single number.

Comment: In fact I am only asking for (samples of existing) "instructive graphical displays". If there aren't any: what a pity! If there is only one:I would be happy to see it. (I cannot see, which discussions are required to answer my question. Am I too naive?)

Comment: Also, this website's guidelines suggest to ask and answer specific questions (https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), and for good reasons, I think. Making a thread tractable facilitates both answering and perusing.

Comment: Please tell me, what is unspecific about my question? In which respect is it vague? (I admit it is broad, because it allows for a lot of answers. This makes it a "big list" question. But what is bad about "big list" questions?)

Comment: For example, answering about excitatory synapses would require me to discuss how they were measured with sufficient detail that someone could evaluate what I would present. There are some technicalities that are important in those studies. It would also require me to mention in which cells their distribution was evaluated. Additionally, and based on the previous comments, it would be necessary to present the two contrasting theories and how they take this evidence into account. All these would be required in my view in order to give a comprehensive answer, just for this part of your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65237/discussion-between-hans-stricker-and-vkehayas).